# Account Status should set to Modified when an Account is Edited

Tags: trigger, formula, configuration

I need to set the Status Picklist on Account object to "Modified" When an account is edited.

Thanks!!

Comment: OK, good to know. Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Mohan. What's your question on doing so ? Please update your post to actually contain a question and share with us how or why this is challenging or confusing to you. Then we'll reopen this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a workflow to update fields. Go to:

1. Setup-> Create (under Build)->Workflow & Approvals -> Workflow Rules.
2. Click on "New Rule", select object "**Account**", click next.
3. Insert Rule Name and select the Evaluation Criteria, for this case select **"created, and every time it's edited"**.
4. After that you need to insert you **Rule Criteria**. 
   I will probably go for a formula in your **Rule Criteria** and select the field **`LastModifiedDate`** for your logic.

A formula like this will be the best option:

```
ISCHANGED( LastModifiedDate )
```

When done you can use a Workflow Action in the next page after clicking on **"Save and Next"**.

1. Add Workflow Action.
2. Select **"New Field Update"**.
3. Insert Name and pick your **"Field to Update"**. There you need to select the pick list and the value that it will be inserted on that field.

That should do it.

Don't forget to make your Workflow Rule active, they are not active by default.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use point and click to serve the purpose using Workflow Rule, which is ultimate tool provided by Salesforce.

1. Create a Workflow Rule on `Some__c` object
2. Set Evaluation Criteria to "Every time a record is created or edited"
3. Change Rule Criteria to "Formula evaluates to true"
4. Enter the following formula:

   ISCHANGED ( Some__c.picklist__c )
5. Under Immediate Workflow Actions, create a Field Update for `Some__c.date_status_changed__c`
6. Enter the following formula to update the field:

   NOW()
7. Save and run to test the rule is working or not.